# Return to ec2-user from a custom user

Tags: linux, bash, centos, python, amazon-ec2

When creating an ec2 instance I use a bootstrap script. On the instance I install and configure an nginx web server. For security reasons, I need to create a new user (www-data).

The www-data user is created using:

```
sudo groupadd www-data
sudo adduser www-data -g www-data
sudo passwd -d www-data
```

Additional I run some python scripts on that machine. For this I used virtualenv. I run the following flow:

```
su www-data
pip install --user virtualenv 
python -m virtualenv $VIRTUALENV_NAME
cd /path/to/bin
source activate
pip install `stuff`
deactivate
```

My problem occurs after the above flow when I want to return to ec2-user. In the terminal typing `exit` does the job. Inside the bootstrap script it will exit the script.

I've tried with `su ec2-user` but it asks for password. I don't have one.

How to return to ec2-user from another user? Or how to workaround it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *type* this

```
su www-data
whatever
something-else
exit
```

`su` starts an additional shell as `www-data` user. Then you *type* consecutive commands, they are executed in this shell, so `exit` brings you back to the old shell.

If these commands are in a script, `whatever` won't be executed in the additional shell. The original shell will wait for `su` to exit before it goes to `whatever` and further. If you run such a script (a file like `script.sh` with proper shebang) from terminal, you'll be taken to an *interactive* shell. Type `exit` there by hand to continue with the script.

Now inside a bootstrap script there is no TTY attached, `su www-data` cannot start an interactive shell and exits immediately. The rest of the script is executed (obviously not as `www-data` user); and if there is `exit` somewhere, it will exit the script.

The cleanest way to deal with it is to insert `whatever` and `something-else` into a separate helper script, then you can invoke in your main script

```
su www-data -c "/path/to/the/helper/script"
```

The main script will wait for `su` to exit. When it happens, any following line is executed by the original user.

Another way is like this:

```
su www-data -c 'whatever; something-else'
```

or equivalently

```
su www-data -c '
whatever
something-else
'
```

The latter approach may be troublesome if the commands need quoting. There is no such problem with an additional script.

Comment: Another option could be a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) - `su www-data <<EOF` ... `EOF`